# how can I use parcel.js to run p5.js code?

Tags: p5.js, parceljs

I've lately been using parcel.js with react apps and it's been very user friendly.

I'm following along to a Coding Train tutorial and parcel for whatever reason is not running the code.

https://github.com/CodingTrain/website/tree/master/CodingChallenges/CC_001_StarField/P5

When I run this with live server, no errors and everything runs correctly.

When I attempt to run it with parcel.js, there are no errors, it just doesn't run, nothing renders.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that Parcel.js doesn't put variables defined in src'd scripts into the global scope by default, and p5.js depends on these globals by default (`setup` and `draw` in particular). You could solve the problem by making `speed`, `setup` and `draw` in sketch.js, and `Star` in Star.js, properties of `window` (or, equivalently,  `global`).  See the example below, which works when built with `parcel index.html`.

(This method has the benefit of preserving access to the familiar (global) p5.js commands without the need for a prefix, but might give complications with globals being overwritten if you're using other libraries.)

```js
 
//sketch.js   
let stars = [];

window.speed = undefined;

window.setup = function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  for (let i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
    stars[i] = new Star();
  }
}

window.draw = function draw() {
  speed = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, 50);
  background(0);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    stars[i].update();
    stars[i].show();
  }
}

//Star.js
window.Star = function Star() {
  this.x = random(-width, width);
  this.y = random(-height, height);
  this.z = random(width);
  this.pz = this.z;

  this.update = function() {
    this.z = this.z - speed;
    if (this.z < 1) {
      this.z = width;
      this.x = random(-width, width);
      this.y = random(-height, height);
      this.pz = this.z;
    }
  };

  this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    noStroke();

    var sx = map(this.x / this.z, 0, 1, 0, width);
    var sy = map(this.y / this.z, 0, 1, 0, height);

    var r = map(this.z, 0, width, 16, 0);
    ellipse(sx, sy, r, r);

    var px = map(this.x / this.pz, 0, 1, 0, width);
    var py = map(this.y / this.pz, 0, 1, 0, height);

    this.pz = this.z;

    stroke(255);
    line(px, py, sx, sy);
  };
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>StarField_p5.js</title>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      canvas {
        vertical-align: top;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.0.0/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.0.0/lib/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

    <script src="./Star.js"></script>
    <script src="./sketch.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main></main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you could use [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode) of P5.js to set things up without globals (See also thread [here](https://discourse.processing.org/t/run-p5js-with-parcel/9681/4) - the code sample of which has now had its P5.js dependency removed, but you can look at the commit history). This has the downside that the familiar P5.js / processing functions have to be prefixed with an object reference, minimally something like `s.createCanvas` (the methods often seem to depend on being bound properly in object orientated style). It is likely the safer approach if other libraries are involved though, especially as p5.js defines lots of globals with common names like `random`, `map` and `height` if it isn't used in instance mode.

Something like this:

```js
 
// index.js
// I've combined sketch.js and Star.js here to make
// it easier to share variable speed

const myp5 = new p5((s) => {
  
  const stars = [];

  let speed =1;

  s.setup = function setup() {
    s.createCanvas(600, 600);
    for (let i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
      stars[i] = new Star();
    }
  };

  s.draw = function draw() {
    speed = s.map(s.mouseX, 0, s.width, 0, 50);
    s.background(0);
    s.translate(s.width / 2, s.height / 2);
    for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      stars[i].update();
      stars[i].show();
    }
  };

 function Star() {
   this.x = s.random(-s.width, s.width);
   this.y = s.random(-s.height, s.height);
   this.z = s.random(s.width);
   this.pz = this.z;

   this.update = function () {
     this.z = this.z - speed;
     if (this.z < 1) {
       this.z = s.width;
       this.x = s.random(-s.width, s.width);
       this.y = s.random(-s.height, s.height);
       this.pz = this.z;
     }
   };

   this.show = function () {
     s.fill(255);
     s.noStroke();

     var sx = s.map(this.x / this.z, 0, 1, 0, s.width);
     var sy = s.map(this.y / this.z, 0, 1, 0, s.height);

     var r = s.map(this.z, 0, s.width, 16, 0);
     s.ellipse(sx, sy, r, r);

     var px = s.map(this.x / this.pz, 0, 1, 0, s.width);
     var py = s.map(this.y / this.pz, 0, 1, 0, s.height);

     this.pz = this.z;

     s.stroke(255);
     s.line(px, py, sx, sy);
   };
 }
},'sketch1');
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>StarField_p5.js</title>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      canvas {
        vertical-align: top;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.0.0/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.0.0/lib/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sketch1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: fantastic, thanks again! i was learning about this alternative approach more today and your follow up bolsters what i've been learning.

Comment: Strictly, you can get I think get rid of the need for the prefix with something like ```const [background,translate] = ['background','translate'].map(x=>s[x].bind(s)); ``` .... perhaps introspecting s and its prototype to distinguish functions and to save typing all the names twice. Might be worth doing if you're copying and pasting a lot of p5.js code. Or maybe somebody knows a better method?

Comment: oh that's an interesting idea. But no i don't plan to be copying and pasting much p5, the plan is to be writing it more and more :)